# Using epsilon delta to prove $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^3-5x)(2+\cos(\frac{1}{x-1}))$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

How would I use the epsilon-delta definition to show that the limit $$\lim_{x\to 1}(x^3-5x)\left(2+\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\right)$$ does not exist?

Comment: How epsilon-delta definition shows that a limit does not exist?